# Migrate SQL users table but keep their original id's

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migrate

How to copy users table between wordpress databases but keep their original id from the origin table?

when I export -> import users to a new table, the new id's are written incrementally instead of getting the original id's

I expect user id 567 in the new table to get the user id 567 in the new table even though there are no users in id numbers 2 to 566.

Comment: why does it matter? The ID is just to make sure the record has a unique identifier. It shouldn't have any other meaning or significance.

Comment: it does this time because i need to transfer courses access that are written by user id in the course tables (learndash).

but i found the solution, in the export sql you have a checkbox for auto_increment, if i uncheck it, it keeps the original id's

Comment: You should write that in the Answers section then - you're allowed to answer your own question, and accept that answer. And others may then upvote it if they find it useful in future :-)

Comment: thank you very much, i have now wrote the solution as an answer to my question, see if you can see it.

Comment: No I don't see it...did you forget to submit it?

Answer (score 1):

when you export you database via phpmyadmin, in the "Object creation options" you can tick off the "auto_increment value" to export the database in the original id's as the table you are exporting.